# Search age of person in dictionary

Tags: python

I have a function that asks for the person their first and last name and then prints their age but i am having trouble entering the if statement, it is always skipping it.

My dictionary prints like this on the command line: {('name','subname'):19)}

```
l_name = raw_input("Enter last name")
f_name = raw_input("Enter first name")
if (l_name, f_name) in my_dict.items():
    age = my_dict[l_name,f_name]
    print age
```

thanks in advance

Comment: i just made those changes which i noticed it was wrong but still doesnt enter if statement

Comment: Could it be that you have the order mixed up? if you meant _surname_ instead of _subname_, then you're looking for ('last name', 'first name') in a dictionary with ('first name', 'last name') tuples.

Comment: I doubt that your dictionary prints like this `{('name','subname'):19)}` because that is invalid Python (unmatched parentheses).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
if (l_name, f_name) in my_dict:
```

See it working online: [ideone](http://ideone.com/H72mU)

Comment: Yes you are correct i didnt even notice that but it still skips the if statement

Comment: @user998316: I've linked to ideone where you can see that it works. Perhaps you input incorrect values?

Comment: yes you are right, im sorry, i didnt noticed i had the items() in my if statement.

Answer (score 0):

You were very close.  Just do the lookup using a tuple instead of using *and*.

Here is the working code:

```
age_dict = dict([
    (('tom', 'hanks'), 55),
    (('al', 'pacino'), 71),
])

l_name = raw_input("Enter last name: ")
f_name = raw_input("Enter first name: ")
if (l_name, f_name) in age_dict:
    age = age_dict[l_name,f_name]
    print age
```

That gives a user-session like this:

```
Enter last name: al
Enter first name: pacino
71
```

Answer (score 0):

also you can do it in a simple way just like that...
a = {
'ali ahmad': 34
}
i = input('enter your name')

if i in a.keys():
age = a[i]
print(age)
else:
print('invalid data has been entered')

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).